# Python Input function in atom prevents code from running

Tags: python, input, user-input, atom-editor

I have atom installed. I can write print("hello") and get hello returned but I tried using the input() function in the following format and it appears that the code doesn't even give me an option to put anything in:

[first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB2xw.png)

[input issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crgEt.png)

Comment: I assume you're using `script` so I closed your question under an existing one that covers the same problem. If not, LMK and [edit] to add what package you're using, since Atom doesn't support running code out of the box. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: I am using script however the answers in that other question aren't solving the issue. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? `script` doesn't support input, so you have to use something else.